# How to add a log into email merge from excel to outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using the folowing code to send out surveys to my customers. Now I'm looking for a way to add in the email my company's logo, however I'm not sure on how to change the code in order to achieve this.

would be possible to get your support on this question?

Thank you.
Marcelo

```
Sub mailmerge1()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim table1 As ListObject
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    Set table1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("K2:M17")
    ' You can also use a sheet name here.
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

    For i = 1 To table1.ListRows.Count

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)



    Range("J2") = i
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "tsc@volvo.com"
        .To = Range("J5")
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Let us know what you think"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        '.Display
            ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
            ' display the e-mail message.
        .send

    End With

    Next i
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Example*

```
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "tsc@volvo.com"
        .To = Range("J5")
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Let us know what you think"
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\0m3r\Pictures\Hello.png", olByValue, 0
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & vbCrLf & _
            "<BODY><IMG src=""cid:Hello.png"" width=200> </BODY>"
        .Display
            ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
            ' display the e-mail message.
'        .Send

    End With
```

*Make sure not to use spaces on your logo file name-*